# @Html.DropDownList does not set selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have an MVC 4 application and what I am trying to do is to list the events of a specific booking (together with some information about the booking - this by using viewbags) in the same page (using the Events model only). So that goes fine until I add a dropdown-list to change the statusCode of that booking (that all the listing events are related to).

```
@Html.DropDownList("StatusCodeList")
```

Whatever I do, it doesn't change. Please help me to find out why !

**Models**

```
public class Booking
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookingId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Event Title")]
        public string EventTitle { get; set; }      

        [DisplayName("Requester's Name")]
        public string UserFullName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public System.DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Event Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public System.DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Login")]
        public string Login { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("NetworkID")]
        public string NetworkID { get; set; }

        public string BookingTotalCost { get; set; }

         [ForeignKey("StatusCode")]
        public int StatusCodeId { get; set; }
        public virtual StatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Event Type is required.")]
        [ForeignKey("CateringType")]
        public int CateringTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual CateringType CateringType { get; set; }

        public List<Event> Events { get; set; }

    }

public class Event
    {    
         [Key]
        public int EventId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Event Leader is required")]
        [DisplayName("Event Leader")] 
        public string EventLeader { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Budget Code is required")]
        [DisplayName("Budget Code")] 
        public string EventBudgetCode { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Special Requirements")]
        public string SpecialRequirements { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Event Cost")]
        public string EventTotalCost { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Participants are required")]
        [Range(1, 300, ErrorMessage = "Participants must be </br> between 1 and 300")]
        [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Max 3 digits")]
         [DisplayName("Participants")]
        public string EventParticipants { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Room is required")]
        [DisplayName("Room Number")] 
        [ForeignKey("Room")]
        public int RoomId { get; set; }
        public virtual Room Room { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Start Time is required")]
        [DisplayName("Start Time")] 
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime EventStartDateTime { get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "End Time is required")]
        [DisplayName("End Time")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DateEnd(DateStartProperty = "EventStartDateTime")]
        public DateTime EventEndDateTime { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Booking")]
        public int BookingId { get; set; }
        public virtual Booking Booking { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dietary Requirements are required")]
        [DisplayName("Dietary Requirement")] 
        [ForeignKey("DietaryRequirement")]
        public int DietaryRequirementId { get; set; }
        public virtual DietaryRequirement DietaryRequirement { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CateringItem> CateringItems { get; set; }    

    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult RequestDetails(int id)
        {


            var eventList = from s in SystemDB.Events
                            where s.BookingId == id
                            select s;

            Booking booking = SystemDB.Bookings.Find(id);

            ViewBag.Date = booking.EventDate.ToShortDateString();
            ViewBag.BookingId = id;

            ViewBag.Requester = booking.UserFullName;
            ViewBag.RequesterEmail = booking.NetworkID + "@gmail.com";


            var sum = (from s in SystemDB.Events.ToList()
                       where s.BookingId == id
                       select Convert.ToDecimal(s.EventTotalCost)).Sum();


            if (booking.BookingTotalCost == null && sum == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.BookingTotalCost = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.BookingTotalCost = sum;

            }

            TempData["BookingId"] = id;

            var statuscodes = SystemDB.StatusCodes.Where(s => s.StatusCodeId != 1);
            ViewBag.StatusCodeList = new SelectList(statuscodes, "StatusCodeId", "StatusCodeName", booking.StatusCodeId);


            return View(eventList);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("RequestDetails")]
        public ActionResult PostRequestDetails(int id)
        {

            TempData["BookingId"] = id;

            var eventList = from s in SystemDB.Events
                            where s.BookingId == id
                            select s;

            ViewBag.BookingId = id;              

            Booking booking = SystemDB.Bookings.Find(id);

            ViewBag.Date = booking.EventDate.ToShortDateString();
            ViewBag.BookingId = id;

            ViewBag.Requester = booking.UserFullName;
            ViewBag.RequesterEmail = booking.NetworkID + "@gmail.com";

            var sum = (from s in SystemDB.Events.ToList()
                       where s.BookingId == id
                       select Convert.ToDecimal(s.EventTotalCost)).Sum();

            booking.BookingTotalCost = sum.ToString();

            var statuscodes = SystemDB.StatusCodes.Where(s => s.StatusCodeId != 1);
            ViewBag.StatusCodeList = new SelectList(statuscodes, "StatusCodeId", "StatusCodeName", booking.StatusCodeId);


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                SystemDB.Entry(booking).State = EntityState.Modified;

                SystemDB.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("RequestList", "Admin", new { id = id });
            }


            return View(eventList);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<CateringBookingSystem.Models.Event>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<span><b>Booking for: </b>@ViewBag.Date</span> <span style="padding-left:20px;"><b>Total Cost: </b>£@ViewBag.BookingTotalCost</span> <span style="padding-left:20px;"><b>Requester: </b><a href="mailto:'@ViewBag.RequesterEmail'?Subject=Catering%20enquiry" target="_top">@ViewBag.Requester</a></span> <span style="padding-left:20px;"><b>Status: </b> @Html.DropDownList("StatusCodeList")  </span>

      <table id="listTable" style="width:100%" >
    <tr style="color:white;">
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventLeader)
        </th>
        <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventStartDateTime)
        </th>
         <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventEndDateTime)
        </th>
         <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Room.RoomNumber)
        </th>
         <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventParticipants)
        </th>
        <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventTotalCost)
        </th>        
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{       
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventLeader)
        </td>
        <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventStartDateTime)

             </td>
     <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventEndDateTime)

             </td>

          <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Room.RoomNumber)

             </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventParticipants)
        </td>

        <td>

            £@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventTotalCost)

             </td>

            <td>
              @Html.ActionLink("Amend", "EditEventForEventList", new { EventId = item.EventId,  Amend = "True" }) |

              <a class="clicker" dialogid="@item.EventId" href="#"> View Catering</a> |
                <div class="dialog @item.EventId " title=""> 
                     <p>@{Html.RenderAction("ViewEvent", "Home", new { EventId = item.EventId });}</p>
                     </div>

                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEventFromEventList", new { id = item.EventId }) 
        </td>     

    </tr>
}    
</table>
    <div style="padding-top:50px;">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </div>
}
```

Comment: Your not binding your dropdown to a property. Assuming you want `StatusCodeId` to contain the value of the selected option, then `@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.StatusCodeId, (SelectList)ViewBag.StatusCodeList)`

Comment: i tried like that but it didnt work : @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.FirstOrDefault().Booking.StatusCodeId, (SelectList)ViewBag.StatusCodeList)

Comment: That does not look even remotely what I stated it needed to be! But none of this makes sense anyway. You post method only has a single parameter `int id`. What is the point of it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: int id is the booking id that the event list shown on the view is related to.

what i am trying is to change the status code for the booking using a dropdown-list

Comment: Which is what I showed above does, but you POST method only has a parameter for `id`, not for `StatusCodeId`.

Comment: ok i just tried using int StatusCodeId as a parameter but comes up as a null...

Comment: Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CateringBookingSystem.Models.Event>' does not contain a definition for 'StatusCodeId' and no extension method 'StatusCodeId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CateringBookingSystem.Models.Event>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Of course it doesn't. `StatusCodeId` is a property of `Booking`, not `Event`. You appear to rendering a Details view of a list of `Event`. If you want to edit a `Booking`, create a view to edit a booking.

Comment: @Wizeman1986 you shouldn't use a ViewBag,instead create a strongly typed view bound to a viewmodel that contains all your view data.